# How to connect vb.net on my mysql database with windows 7

Tags: mysql, vb.net, windows-7, odbc

I have some problems with a vb.net application.
My application was perfectly working on XP, but now on my windows 7, each time I want to connect to localhost, I have a driver problem (in french, that's why I don't put it here)...

Do you know were does it come from? 
My odbc driver is up to date...

Comment: I think we need some clarification. Are you attempting to connect to a MySql database from a VB.NET app? Phpmyadmin has nothing to do with VB.NET.

Comment: I'm sorry, my database is provided and hosted localy by phpmyadmin. I'm attempting to connect to this database with vb.net.

Comment: if i remember correct you need myodbc to connect via .net http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: No. Don't use the odbc connector. Use the native Connector/.NET

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Connector/.NET.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

In your project, you should be able to add a reference to MySql.Data. You can then create your connection string.

```
Dim oMySqlConn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
oMySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;"  & _
                              "Database=mySQLDatabase;"  & _
                              "User ID=myUsername;"  & _
                              "Password=myPassword;"  & _
                              "Command Logging=false"
oMySqlConn.Open()
```

`localhost` can be replaced with either an IP address or 'servename.com'

Comment: @drummaniac: can you 'ping' the IP address to your MySql server?

Comment: yes, it's hosted by wamp, and I can change values on the database with a little Ajax app'